# CSS animation - Animating image left to right and increasing height along an angled path

Tags: css, css-animations

At the moment I'm using css animation to move an image from the left to the right of the screen. This works without issue.

What I want to do is actually have the animation start at a certain height then as it animates to the other side of the screen I want the height to gradually increase. So basically it moves upwards on a angle. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Do I set several key frames and change the screen position there?

CSS

```
/* This is the controls for Santas sledge*/
.santa {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15%;
    left: -75%;
}

/* This is the controls for Santas sledge*/

.santa {
    -webkit-animation: santa-move 1s 1s ease-out forwards;

    animation-duration: 26s;    
    -webkit-animation-duration: 26s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes santa-move {
        100% { left: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cZ9wP/

Just add `top`.

```
@-webkit-keyframes santa-move {
    100% { left: 100%; top: 50%; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `transform: scale();` like so:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zu5X2/2/)

```
 .santa {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: -75%;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

 .santa {
    -webkit-animation: santa-move 1s 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: santa-move 1s 1s ease-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 26s;
    animation-duration: 26s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes santa-move {
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
}
@keyframes santa-move {
    100% {
        left:100%;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
}
```